# Why does `(fboundp #'method)' return nil?

Tags: oop, common-lisp

Let's say I define

```
(defclass test-class ()
  ((greet :accessor greet
      :initform "Hi")))
```

and

```
(defmethod test-method ((instance test-class))
  (print (greet instance)))
```

Why is it that `(fboundp 'test-method)` evaluates to `t`, but `(fboundp #'test-method)` evaluates to `nil` while the reverse happens for `(functionp 'test-method)` and `(functionp #'test-method)`? I thought methods in CLOS were just functions associated to a particular generic that were then dispatched according to the types of the arguments.

I ask this because I am trying to define a function that checks whether a symbol is a method or not:

```
(defun check-method (method specializers)
  (and (fboundp method) (find-method method nil specializers nil)))
```

This works when I call `(check-method #'test-method '(test-class))` but errors out with `(check-method 'test-method '(test-class))` saying that there is no applicable method for `find-method` given the arguments. I'm hoping some clarity on the nature of functions and methods will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fboundp` tests if a *symbol* (name) has its function slot assigned, `functionp` tests if its argument is itself a function, not the name of one.

So `(fboundp 'test-method)` is `t` because the symbol `test-method` has a function associated with it, and `(fboundp #'test-method)` should be raising an error because its argument isn't a symbol (Are you really getting `nil` instead? Which Common Lisp implementation are you using?).

`(functionp 'test-method)` is `nil` because its argument is a symbol, but `(functionp #'test-method)` is `t` because it's getting a function.

Change your `check-method` to

```lisp
(defun check-method (method specializers)
  (and (functionp method) (find-method method nil specializers nil)))
```

and call it like `(check-method #'test-method '(test-class))` and it'll work (Both ways you tried calling your definition of it should raise errors). A version like

```lisp
(defun check-method (method specializers)
  (and (if (symbolp method) (fboundp method) (functionp method))
       (find-method (if (symbolp method) (symbol-function method) method)
                    nil specializers nil)))
```

will accept both forms.